# Domain Logic, DAL, Database - Where to place what, where? and how to interact with them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, logic, data-access-layer

I have the following task:

I have to create the following: Domain Logic, Data Access Layer, Database.

I will also have to create an ASP.Net Page to work with the aforementioned pieces (ASP.Net is only part of the system, there may be a desktop app etc).

I want to use the Entity Framework as the Data Access Layer, but here is my confusion:
I dont know how I should go about creating the different layers... I cant work out what project type they would be..I would usually use the ADO.Net Entity Framework within a C# Windows Form project with a SQL Database. However, the fact that I will have ASP.Net and Windows Forms possibly using the domain logic confuses me as to how and where I would place each part? The Domain logic, the DAL and the Database..? Also, how would I interact with each layer? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated as I have no clue how to go about this currently.. I hope I explained this reasonably, Thank you.

Comment: You can place an EF4 EDMX file in a Class Library and then reference that library from your ASP.NET project.  Same goes for the other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I would create separate projects for each, i.e:

- Library project that houses the models
- Another library project for business/domain logics
- Web project (ASP.NET / MVC)

With that setup, you can reuse your library projects in WinForm, WPF, etc... project by just referencing the libraries.

Comment: +1 the most simple setup for n-layer architecture applications